# sqlsrv_num_rows não funciona

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho um site que ta sendo feito com PHP + SQL SERVER, e para efetuar o login precisa do código do cliente, e ele coloca lá só que sempre diz que está incorreto, sendo que está correto.

Aparentemente o `sqlsrv_num_rows` nao ta funcionando, pq eu coloco o login correto e nao entra no site que eu fiz.

Código de validação de login:

```
    <?php 
session_start();

$serverName = "10.0.0.0.0";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"banco", "UID"=>"usuario", "PWD"=>"senha" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$var1 = $_POST['codMont']; 

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM AB7030 AB7,ABB030 ABB,AB6030 AB6, AA1030 AA, SA1030 SA
WHERE   ABB.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
AND AB7.D_E_L_E_T_ ='' 
AND AB6.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
AND SA.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
AND ABB.ABB_FILIAL = AB6.AB6_FILIAL 
AND ABB.ABB_NUMOS = AB6.AB6_NUMOS 
AND ABB.ABB_FILIAL = AB7.AB7_FILIAL
AND ABB.ABB_NUMOS = AB7.AB7_NUMOS 
AND AB6.AB6_CODCLI = SA.A1_COD
AND AA.AA1_CODTEC = ABB_CODTEC
AND ABB.ABB_CODTEC = '".$var1."'  
AND AB7.AB7_TIPO IN ('1','3')   
        AND AB7_FILIAL = '99'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

if ($row_count > 0 ){
    $_SESSION['codMont'] = $var1;
    header('location:homee.php');
}else{
    unset ($_SESSION['codMont']);
    $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Código do Montador ou senha incorretos. Tente novamente!</div>";
    printf ($mensagem);
    printf ($var1);
}
```

Mesmo eu colocando o código correta ou incorreto nao funciona, sempre diz que não tem cadastro com esse código, sendo que tem sim. Alguém sabe qual seria o problema?

Comment: Já tentou imprimir a primeira linha para ver se o SQL volta mesmo um resultado?

Comment: Coloquei pra imprimir o `$stmt` e a resposta foi `Resource id #6`

Comment: Faz assim para exibir os resultados: $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql); $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt); $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result); print_r($row);

Comment: Deu esse erro: `Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\teste.php on line 37
Código do Montador ou senha incorretos. Tente novamente!`

Comment: E utilizando o seu $stmt? adicionando abaixo da linha do $row_count o seguinte: $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt); print_r($row);

Comment: Agora imprimiu o que eu pedi no `SELECT` e troquei o `if ($row_count > 0 ){...` por `if ($row > 0 )` e funcionou!!! Muito obrigada!!!

Comment: acho que você não deve utilizar o $row>0, no mínimo deveria utilizar um count($row)>0. Mas creio que ainda não chegamos a um resultado correto.

Comment: Coloquei o `count($row)>0` e funciona direitinho. Pq diz que n chegamos a um resultado correto?

Answer (score 3):

Isto ocorre porque usa por padrão `SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD`, conforme https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017, como no próprio link indica:

> `sqlsrv_num_rows` returns an error for result sets created with this cursor type.
>
> Traduzindo: `sqlsrv_num_rows` retorna um erro para o resultado definido para conjuntos de resultados criados com este tipo de cursor (se referindo ao `SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD`)

Isso deve ser definido no `sql_query`, e são suportados os seguintes parametros para `Scrollable` que deve ser configurado no terceiro parâmetro, o `$options`, conforme abaixo:

```
sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql, array $params, array $options)
```

A opções para `Scrollable` são:

- `SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD` (padrão)

  Permite mover uma linha por vez, começando na primeira linha do conjunto de resultados, até chegar ao final do conjunto de resultados.
- `SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC`

  Permite acessar linhas em qualquer ordem, mas não refletirá as alterações no banco de dados.
- `SQLSRV_CURSOR_DYNAMIC`

  Permite acessar linhas em qualquer ordem e refletirá as alterações no banco de dados.
- `SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET`

  Permite acessar linhas em qualquer ordem. No entanto, um cursor de conjunto de chaves não atualiza a contagem de linhas se uma linha for excluída da tabela (uma linha excluída é retornada sem valores).
- `SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED`, este não esta informado no `php.net` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php), mas como o proprio php.net indica o site da Microsoft então creio que funcione em todas versões atuais (em breve vou detalhar)

  Permite acessar linhas em qualquer ordem. Cria uma consulta de cursor do lado do cliente (lado cliente no caso se refere ao PHP, ou seja o PHP é cliente do servidor do banco, não tem haver com front-end, html e css, o processo é no PHP mesmo, os demais cursores diferente deste ficam do lado do banco)

Sempre que possível, olhe para a documentação, lá tem sessões para exemplos de quase todas APIs, como esta http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php#example-2656

Para o seu caso deve ser algo como:

```
$params = array();
$options =  array( 'Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

if ($row_count > 0 ){
    $_SESSION['codMont'] = $var1;
    header('location:homee.php');
}else{
    unset ($_SESSION['codMont']);
    $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Código do Montador ou senha incorretos. Tente novamente!</div>";
    printf ($mensagem);
    printf ($var1);
}
```

> **Nota:** `sqlsrv_num_rows` pode retornar `0` ou `FALSE`, ou seja vai depender da sua necessidade, no caso `FALSE` é quando algo falhar, e `0` (zero) ocorre quando encontrar zero registros, então no seu caso especifico checar se é maior que zero `> 0` funcionará tanto para zero quanto para false, mas em outros casos isto pode não ser o ideal, ainda mais se necessitar saber o que pode ter ocorrido, por exemplo:
>
> ```
> if ($row_count === false) {
>     echo 'Erro ao obter o total';
> } else {
>     echo "Foram encontrados $row_count resultado(s)";
> }
> ```